# Function Call not working properly

Tags: c++, string, function-calls

here is my function call, it has a prototype and everything compiles fine, except I am not getting the result I want.

```
string lower_case(string x)
{
    transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), ::tolower);

    return x;
}
```

Now this simple function takes the string and make it all lower case, I need to do this numerous time in my code, so instead of rewriting this all of the time, I want to make a function call for it, but I am not getting  the result I want. For example take this code:

```
int main()
{
 string str = "HELLO WORLD";
 lower_case(str);
cout<< str << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

The out put would still be HELLO WORLD instead of hello world, am i calling the function correctly?

Comment: Because you're copying the string and doing the changes on the copy

Comment: how do i get the changed copy back?

Answer (score 5):

When you call functions by value, you copy the object and thus you're dropping the results when you exit the function.

This is the correct way of doing it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

void lower_case(string& x) // No return type needed
{
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), ::tolower);
}

int main()
{
 string str = "HELLO WORLD";
 lower_case(str);

 cout << str;

 return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/u5WcYA

You can pass a **reference** or a **pointer** to the object you want to modify, i.e. to a string object.

In your case you might as well (probably better) use the result value in your function signature:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

string lower_case(string x) // Return type needed
{
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), ::tolower);

    return x;
}

int main()
{
 string str = "HELLO WORLD";
 cout << lower_case(str);

 return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/bZaS6l

In the latter way you make a copy out of the object, operate on that copy and then return the **modified** copy, thus getting the correct result.

Comment: so all you did was change the (string x) to an address in memory by using (string& x)?

Comment: Yes. The main difference between a reference and an actual pointer (which really is an address) is that a reference can't be empty (or null).

Comment: Taking a `string&` *and* return a `string`? This cannot be right. I think you meant for the function to be `void`, didn't you?

Comment: In your first version, you're passing the argument by reference and storing the result there **and** returning the result. Why?

Comment: I did that intentionally to change the minimum from the user's code. Anyway I was expecting observations like these. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change your function to pass value by reference, you can just assign your variable the return value of the function.

```
str = lower_case(str);
```

Use this:

```
int main()
{
 string str = "HELLO WORLD";
 str = lower_case(str);
cout<< str << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually output anything, but assuming you do output it after calling `lower_case`, no `str` would not be changed. The reason is that you're passing the string by value and not by reference (or pointer). So lower_case gets a copy of the original string, which it modifies and which is then promptly thrown away (as you don't use the return value).

To actually change the original string you can do one of two things:

1. Change the parameter to be passed by reference (and optionally remove the return value)
2. actually use the return value

In practice, 1. is a trivial change where the signature would look like this (and requires no other changes):

```
string lower_case(string& x)
```

Here the string is modified in place. As for the second solution, just change the line where the function is called to:

```
str = lower_case(str);
```

and it will also work. Please note that with the second option (potentially) two copies are made: one when `lower_case` is called and one when it's returned (and therefore written back to the original string object, but with a c++11 compiler this will probably transformed into a move, so that would only leave one copy).

Hope this answers your question, but I'd recommend you do a tutorial as those are absolute basics/fundamentals of not just C++ but any programming language.